# Bargain Finder Max Showing Unavailable Routes

Tags: json, sabre

I am using V4 of Bargain Finder Max and am running into an issue with some of the routes/prices I am seeing.

When searching for flights, most flights are not actually available even though the Bargain Finder Max is showing them as available. I have been verifying availability using the Revalidate Itinerary API and by checking carrier website.

An example would be this request for searching a round trip flight from SFO to GSP. Checking with the carrier and with the Revalidate API the first few routes returned are invalid. Even when the revalidate API is used, I am finding the prices to be wildly off compared to carrier advertised prices. Ex: $360 vs $160

How often is the Bargain Finder Max updated? Is there a way to force updates for routes that are being searched for? I understand this will take more time, but getting somewhat accurate data is important.

```
{
    "OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ": {
        "AvailableFlightsOnly": true,
        "TravelPreferences": {
            "TPA_Extensions": {
                "DataSources": {
                    "ATPCO": "Enable",
                    "LCC": "Enable",
                    "NDC": "Enable"
                }
            },
            "CabinPref": [
                {
                    "Cabin": "Y"
                }
            ]
        },
        "OriginDestinationInformation": [
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2023-08-08T00:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "GSP"
                },
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "SFO"
                },
                "RPH": "0"
            },
            {
                "DepartureDateTime": "2023-08-11T00:00:00",
                "DestinationLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "SFO"
                },
                "OriginLocation": {
                    "LocationCode": "GSP"
                },
                "RPH": "1"
            }
        ],
        "POS": {
            "Source": [
                {
                    "PseudoCityCode": "F9CE",
                    "RequestorID": {
                        "CompanyName": {
                            "Code": "TN"
                        },
                        "ID": "1",
                        "Type": "1"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "TPA_Extensions": {
            "IntelliSellTransaction": {
                "RequestType": {
                    "Name": "200ITINS"
                }
            }
        },
        "TravelerInfoSummary": {
            "AirTravelerAvail": [
                {
                    "PassengerTypeQuantity": [
                        {
                            "Code": "ADT",
                            "Quantity": 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "SeatsRequested": [
                1
            ]
        },
        "Version": "v4"
    }
}
```